# Collate data from different tabs to single tabs with reference of the tabs from which the data is copied

Tags: excel, vba, collation

I have a workbook with appx 20-25 worksheets. I want to copy only the filled rows from Row # 4 of each worksheet to a single sheet - "Collate" along with the name of the source worksheet( from where data is copied). Only the filled in rows in each worksheet should be copied(along with worksheet name in first column) in Collate worksheet. Can someone please suggest/provide the vba code to achieve the above.

Comment: For Eg. there are 25 tab A through Y and each tab has header and all the columns are same. I need to copy the data from column A through column Z for row # 5 onwards only if the rows are not blank to a sheet called collate where 1st column(Col A) will be the name of the tag from which the data is copied and row B onwards will be actual data.

Comment: I am using below code -

Comment: which inputs header rows and then accordingly omit the entered rows from the tabs and retrieve remaining rows(if filled in), however does not retrieve the name of the tab in the first column(Col A) of Collate sheet

Comment: Dim i As Integer, 
Dim xTCount As Variant
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Set xWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Sheets(1))
xWs.Name = "Collate"
Worksheets(2).Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=xWs.Range("A1")
For i = 2 To Worksheets.Count
Worksheets(i).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(CInt(xTCount), 0).Copy _
Destination:=xWs.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Count).Row + 1, 1)
Next

Comment: I need data from all the tabs in Collate Tab with Column A specifying name of the tab from which data is copied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have  broken this task into 2 functions/subroutines. 
A Function that adds the column with the name of the tab in each tab - 
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim LASTROW As Long
    On Error Resume Next
        For Each WS In Sheets
            If WS.Name <> "Master" And WS.Name <> "Collate" Then
                With WS
                    LASTROW = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                    .Columns(1).Insert
                    .Range("A1:A" & LASTROW) = WS.Name
                End With
            End If
        Next WS
B. Function that accepts no. of header rows and collates the data from next row(no. of header rows + 1) onwards(including the added column with tab name)-
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim xTCount As Variant
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    LInput:
        xTCount = Application.InputBox("The number of header rows", "", "1")
        If TypeName(xTCount) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
        If Not IsNumeric(xTCount) Then
            MsgBox "Only can enter number", , "Enter Header Rows"
            GoTo LInput
        End If
    Set xWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Sheets(1))
    xWs.Name = "Master"
    Worksheets(2).Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=xWs.Range("A1")
    For I = 2 To Worksheets.Count
        Worksheets(I).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(CInt(xTCount), 0).Copy _
                   Destination:=xWs.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Count).Row + 1, 1)
    Next